# Sudoku Checker- How to check for duplicates in a sub grid

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm going through the book Elements of Programming Interviews and I came upon the problem of writing a solution for a sudoku checker. I was able to easily figure out how to check to ensure that the current element isn't found anywhere else in the current column and row, but it has proven to be non-trivial to check for duplicates in the current sub grid.

The issue I'm having trouble figuring out is how to know which subgrid the current element is in (as you iterate through the 2D array) and where that subgrid starts.

The solution in the book seems to check each subgrid by doing the following:

```
bool isValidSudoku(const vector<vector<int>>& partial_assignment) {
    //Code to check row constraints
    //Code to check col constraints

    //Check region constraints (I'm assuming this is to check each subgrid)

    int region_size = sqrt(partial_assignment.size());
    for (int I = 0; I < region_size; ++I) {
        for (int J = 0; J < region_size; ++J) {
            if (HasDuplicate(partial_assignment, region_size * I),
                region_size * (I + 1), region_size * J,
                region_size * (J + 1)){
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
    return true;

}

//Return true if subarray partial_assignment[start_row : end_row - 1]
//[start_col : end_col -1] contains any duplicates in {1,2,....
// partial_assignment.size()}; otherwise return false.
bool HasDuplicate(const vector<vector<int>>& partial_assignment,
    int start_row, int end_row, int start_col, int end_col) {
    deque<bool> is_present(partial_assignment.size() + 1, false);
    for (int i = start_row; i < end_row;++i) {
        for (int j = start_col; j < end_col;++j) {
            if (partial_assignment[i][j] != 0 &&
                is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
            is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]] = true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So I have a few questions here: **If it has found the region (or subsquare) in the matrix, why does it need to call `has_duplicates()` for each element in that subsquare? I would think that you just need to iterate through every element in that square and simply check if each element has been seen before.**

I was assuming that the input grid would be a normal 2-D grid like this but maybe this is not the case:

```
vector<vector<int>> partial_assignment = { {5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2},
                                {6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8},
                                {1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7},
                                {8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3},
                                {4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1},
                                {7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6},
                                {9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4},
                                {2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5},
                                {3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9}

    };
```

**Also, what is the point of using a `std::deque` to check for duplicates when you can just use an `std::unordered_map`?**

Comment: It's hard to explain concretely why someone chose an implementation strategy over another, at best we can speculate.

Comment: It's unrelated to your questions, but you have a typo in the call of `HasDuplicate`: after `region_size * I`, there shouldn't be a `)`.

Comment: Also, in the other function, `if (partial_assignment[i][j] != 0 && is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]` **]** `)`. Considering how it's used, it could have been a `std::vector<bool>` too, while a `std::unordered_map` seems a bit of an overkill (with too much overhead) for that job.

Answer (score 1):

> If it has found the region (or subsquare) in the matrix, why does it need to call has_duplicates() for each element in that subsquare?

It's not. The loops in `isValidSudoku` iterate from `0` to `region_size - 1`, s for from a standard sudoko from `0` to `2`. Each `I` and `J` are then multiplied by `region_size` to get your start and end rows/columns: `0-2`, `3-5`, and `6-8`. `HasDuplicate` gets called 9 times.

It might be helpful to analyze code by throwing a bunch of `cout <<` statements in each loop to print out the variables as the loop iterates.

Comment: "It might be helpful to analyze code by throwing a bunch of cout << statements in each loop to print out the variables as the loop iterates."  or use a debugger...

Comment: @xaxxon Oh, yeah. Even better.

Comment: Right, `HasDuplicate` is only called 9 times for each subgrid. I guess I was more curious about why the nested for loop in is needed in`HasDuplicate` seeing that to check for duplicates in an array, you only need to check if you've seen it before which can be done with one for loop and a hashtable. Do you know why its necessary to use the nested for loop?